# How can I "accept" the autocomplete in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, ide, editor

Sorry if this is a stupid question, for the last ten years I've worked solely in a text editor.

In Netbeans, I'd like to be able to quickly accept the autocomplete and move on. For example:

```
$foo["bar
```

Netbeans will have automatically completed this to:

```
$foo["bar"]
```

My caret/cursor is after the 'r' of bar. At this stage I would love to be able to hit one key and move to after the ] or even the " and then the ]. I can use the right keyboard arrow but that is impractical/painful. They must have thought of this by version 8? It really interrupts my flow and right now I'm just retyping the characters myself as it's quicker than moving my hand to the arrow keys.

I've scoured Netbean's menus, help, StackOverflow, Google. I think the answer will be very simple but I'm not sure what I should be searching for. I may just be very dim.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `end` key to jump past the autocompleted characters.